# Connection lost - socket hang up

Tags: javascript, sql-server, express

i'm following a tutorial on how to connect to a database with Node.js / Express / MsSql but when i run the code it says that :

```js
ConnectionError: Connection lost - socket hang up
    at C:\stage\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:71:17
    at Connection.onError (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1042:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Connection.emit (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1065:18)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1667:12)
    at Connection.socketEnd (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1693:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1433:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Connection lost - socket hang up
      at ConnectionError (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1667:54)
      at Connection.socketEnd (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1693:12)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\stage\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1433:14)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}
RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.
    at Request._query (C:\stage\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:491:37)
    at Request._query (C:\stage\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:363:11)
    at Request.query (C:\stage\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:427:12)
    at C:\stage\index.js:16:17
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\stage\node_modules\mssql\lib\global-connection.js:56:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21) {
  code: 'ENOCONN'
}
```

and here's my code :

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {  
  user: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx',
  server: 'xxxxx', 
  port: xxxxx
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('SELECT patient.nom,patient.PRENOM ,patient.DATENAIS FROM patient WHERE rownum<=10', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

here's the package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "stage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mssql": "^7.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

I've tried evverything i knew but i can't find where my problem come from. I've tried to look at my database to see if there's anything that prevent from connecting to it but nop. I've also thought about the fact that it could be my firewall or proxy that block from connecting but i don't know how to check if it causes problems. So if anyone knows what could my problem be or at least somewhere to search because i haven't found any fixes.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: i'll edit ty for your advice

Comment: Add the relevant `package.json`.

Comment: You don't have specified the SQL Server version: Azure or Local? If local is Express or developer? You can reach the SQL from Azure Data Studio or SSMS? Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/node-js-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs).